# Close Software Window over API

Tags: automation, logging, .net-framework, c#, api

I am using a third party Software, which has an internal functionality HPT (Hex-Post-Treatment) when Merging HEX files. I can't tell which Software and so on, however, hope I can explain. The software calls an external batch file, which in turn calls an external .EXE. So, the Software passes control to externals. I'm using an API and C# with Visual Studio to communicate with the Software, get the Log-path and read out the Log file..

The Software is logging which I am reading out in my .EXE. First, I created a new Thread in my .EXE, because this speeds up the Software's performance. Now, after successful and completed processing of the Software, I have to close the opened widget for Merging in the Software, for the Software to complete logging and append crucial information. I need the "complete" log file, i.e. read the appended information from Log file. So I need to close the widget, before my external completes.

And, when my Code in the .EXE is through and I didn't close the widget, then the Software throws an error and can't complete or save the new Merge in the database.

Can anyone help?

[Image from Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOhif.png)

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing fromn your question. If you have any coding related questions you can ask in StackOverflow. To close any program you can use `taskkill` command in CMD or `TerminateProcess()` in C/C++.

Comment: Basically a software triggers in a process an external executable. The Software opens a smaller window for the process. I need to close the smaller window from the external executable, so the software is logging on. I need to read out the Log file in the external application.

Comment: I dont want to kill or close the whole program, but only the smaller window for the logging. I want to close it by automated pressing "OK" in the Window of the above picture.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I could handle the window and sent it messages.

IntPtr windowPtr = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Merge Revision from CBs");
SendMessage(windowPtr, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

The window closed but the software did not the same as if manually clicked the "OK" button in this window.

Then the window containing the Button was found and sent it the messages:

SendMessage(window, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
SendMessage(window, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

Again the window closed, but not delivered the right result.
The result is, that the Log file is updated.

I think, there might be security barriers, because, the window in the first place (Merge Widget) contains >250 windows, which can't be identified with spy++.

Greetings.